# Jest's test match does not pick my test files

Tags: jestjs, puppeteer

Hey I can't get `testMatch` to pick up my test file. Here's my config:

```
module.exports = {
    preset: 'jest-puppeteer',
    testMatch: [
        '**/tests/**/?(*.)+spec.js'
    ]
};
```

My directory layout:

```
- Automation
    -  jest.config.js
    - tests
        - single-property
            - index.spec.js
```

Output:

```
No tests found, exiting with code 1
Run with `--passWithNoTests` to exit with code 0
In C:\Users\<user_name>\WebstormProjects\Automation
  4 files checked.
  testMatch: **/tests/**/?(*.)+spec.js - 0 matches
  testPathIgnorePatterns: \\node_modules\\ - 4 matches
  testRegex:  - 0 matches
Pattern:  - 0 matches
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

`'**/tests/**/*.spec.js'`

Answer (score -1):

add this to end of your `package.json` file

```
"jest": {
  "globals": {
    "ts-jest": {
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json"
    }
  },
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["ts","js"],
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "./node_modules/ts-jest/preprocessor.js"
  },
  "testMatch": [
    "**/tests/**/*.spec.(ts|js)"
  ],
  "testEnvironment": "node"
}
```